# Fluent NHibernate mapping to return description from lookup table

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

We have the following database structure:

```
UserTeam table
Id (PK, int not null)
UserId (FK, int, not null)
TeamId (FK, int, not null)
RoleId (FK, int, not null)

libRole table
Id (PK, int not null)
Description (varchar(255), not null)
```

And we have an entity as follows:

```
public class UserTeam
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }
    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

We are using Fluent NHibernate and configuring NHibernate automatically (ie, using Automapping classes with overrides).

We are trying to get JUST the description column from the libRole table into the "Role" property on the UserTeam table, but really struggling.  The following is the closest we have got:

```
public class UserTeamMap : IAutoMappingOverride<UserTeam>
{
    public void Override( FluentNHibernate.Automapping.AutoMapping<UserTeam> mapping )
    {
        mapping.References( m => m.User ).Column( "UserId" );
        mapping.References( m => m.Team ).Column( "TeamId" );

        mapping.Join("Role", join =>
            {
                join.Fetch.Join();
                join.KeyColumn( "Id" );
                join.Map( x => x.Role, "Description" );
            } );
    }

}
```

Which generates the following SQL:

```
SELECT
    TOP (@p0)  this_.Id as Id70_0_,
    this_.RoleId as RoleId70_0_,
    this_.TeamId as TeamId70_0_,
    this_.UserId as UserId70_0_,
    this_1_.Description as Descript2_71_0_ 
FROM
    [UserTeam] this_ 
inner join
    libRole this_1_ 
        on this_.Id=this_1_.Id;
```

Close, but NHibernate is using the Id column on both the UserTeam table and the libRole table in the join, when it should be doing on `this_.RoleId=this_1_.Id`

What are we missing?  We don't really want to create a "libRole" entity within the application, as all we really care about is the description values - which are user configurable, so we can't just use an enum either.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Join` uses the primary key of the parent table. Its not possible to change this to a foreign key. See the [docs](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/#mapping-declaration-join) for further details on what is possible with `Join`.

In this situation I would recommend creating an entity for the lookup. But if you really want to take this approach you could map the property with a formula, i.e.

```
Map(x => x.Role).Formula("(select description from libRole where Id = RoleId)");
```

Note this isn't perfect because it uses `RoleId` so if the query has another table with a column named `RoleId` then the DBMS will complain when trying to execute the SQL.

Comment: Thanks penfold.  We thought about the formula route, but would prefer to avoid that due to both the reason you mention and because it's unlikely to be as efficient as a sql join (not that we're dealing with millions of rows on the libRole table, but still).  Seems odd that there is no way to get NHibernate to read data for an entity from more than one table though?

Comment: It looks not being able to join by foreign key has been an open issue for some time. See [NH-1452](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-1452) and [NH-3143](https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3143). There has been some [work done](https://github.com/Nicaog/nhibernate-core/tree/NH-1681) towards adding this feature but it hasn't been merged with the trunk.

Comment: Guess there's no way around it really.  In the end we actually removed the Role property from the object as it wasn't being used anywhere - it was a hangover from a design decision taken 10 years ago...  So I've marked this as the answer, thought it would be nice to see nhibernate cater for it at some point - guess we might have to fork and fix ourselves if we really want it though :)